# Intel Centrino N-1000 WIFI problems on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers, wifi-driver

I have a laptop with the Intel Centrino N-1000 wireless card running Ubuntu 12.10.

The Ethernet card works fine, but the wireless card doesn't.

When I click the Networking icon I see that wireless is disabled by hardware switch.

Screenshot:

[image]

I checked the switch on my laptop and it is ON!a

I tried:

-Restarting the Computer

-Copying the ucode firmware file to /lib/firmware

-sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off && sudo iwconfig wlan0 power on

-Going to Settings>Software Sources>Additional Drivers but "No propertiary drivers are in use"

Still the same problem.
EDIT:
After typing sudo rfkill list I discovered the wireless card was soft-blocked and hard-blocked.

I typed sudo rfkill unblock wifi.

Now the card is still hard blocked.

```
user@linux-laptop:~$ sudo rfkill list 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: 'sudo rfkill list' please

Comment: @davidbaumann here you are!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for a solution I found some people having similar problems.
Reseting the BIOS to defaults helped me and them.
I don't know how this worked, but it looks like magic.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Lenovo T410 laptop.  I solved my problem with help from [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1171285) page, which suggests using an older driver.

Comment: Hi, can you quote the relevant parts from that link in your answer?

Comment: OK.  Here's what he says:

Comment: aaargh -- if I could figure out how to format these comments I would cut-and-paste a section of the referenced page. :-(   But, IMO, the description in the link is pretty thorough, and better than a summary.

Comment: The summary should be [edited](https://superuser.com/posts/1190224/edit) into your answer. Quoting parts is fine, but including a description in your own words is better. The reason for including it here is if the link disappears or changes or similar- if you include the information here your answer will still be useful regardless :)